# Incorrect Subdocument Being Updated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a Schema with an array of subdocuments, I need to update just one of them. I do a `findOne` with the ID of the subdocument then cut down the response to just that subdocument at position 0 in the returned array.

No matter what I do, I can only get the first subdocument in the parent document to update, even when it should be the 2nd, 3rd, etc. Only the first gets updated no matter what. As far as I can tell it should be working, but I'm not a MongoDB or Mongoose expert, so I'm obviously wrong somewhere.

```
 var template = req.params.template;
  var page = req.params.page;
  console.log('Template ID: ' + template);

  db.Template.findOne({'pages._id': page}, {'pages.$': 1}, function (err, tmpl) {
    console.log('Matched Template ID: ' + tmpl._id);
    var pagePath = tmpl.pages[0].body;
    if(req.body.file) {
      tmpl.pages[0].background = req.body.filename;
      tmpl.save(function (err, updTmpl) {
        console.log(updTmpl);
        if (err) console.log(err);
      });
      // db.Template.findOne(tmpl._id, function (err, tpl) {
      //   console.log('Additional Matched ID: ' + tmpl._id);
      //   console.log(tpl);
      //   tpl.pages[tmpl.pages[0].number].background = req.body.filename;
      //   tpl.save(function (err, updTmpl){
      //     if (err) console.log(err);
      //   });
      // });
    }
```

In the console, all of the ID's match up properly, and even when I return the updTmpl, it's saying that it's updated the proper record, even though its actually updated the first subdocument and not the one it's saying it has.

The schema just in case:

```
var envelopeSchema = new Schema({
  background: String,
  body: String
});

var pageSchema = new Schema({
  background: String,
  number: Number,
  body: String
});

var templateSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  envelope: [envelopeSchema],
  pagecount: Number,
  pages: [pageSchema]
});
templateSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Template", templateSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you need req.body.file to be set in order for the update to execute I would recommend checking that before you run the query.

Also, is that a typo and req.body.file is supposed to be req.body.filename? I will assume it is for the example.

Additionally, and I have not done serious testing on this, but I believe your call will be more efficient if you specify your Template._id:

```
var template_id = req.params.template,
    page_id = req.params.page;

if(req.body.filename){

    db.Template.update({_id: template_id, 'pages._id': page_id},
        { $set: {'pages.$.background': req.body.filename} },
        function(err, res){
            if(err){
                // err
            } else {
                // success
            }
        });
} else {
    // return error / missing data
}
```

Comment: Yeah, req.body.file is set via a file upload middleware outside the scope of this code provided here. So it's not a typo. :) Your update code worked, I still had to write some extra stuff to get the pagePath I had set as it's needed further in this method, but the update solves the issue I was having with the positional projection operator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't understand documents returned with the positional projection operator.  It always updates an array of subdocuments *positionally*, not by id.  You may be interested in looking at the actual queries that mongoose is building - use `mongoose.set('debug', true)`.

You'll have to either get the entire array, or build your own MongoDB query and go around mongoose.  I would suggest the former; if pulling the entire array is going to cause performance issues, you're probably better off making each of the subdocuments a top-level document - documents that grow without bounds become problematic (at the very least because Mongo has a hard document size limit).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mongoose but the Mongo update query might be:

```
db.Template.update( { "pages._id": page }, { $set: { "pages.$.body" : body } } )
```